# Classic Geometry

Tags: geometry

> In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, $D$ and $E$ are the points on sides $BC$ and $AC$ respectively such that $AE = BD$. If the line joining the circumcentres of triangles $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle BEC$ cut $AC$ and $BC$ at $K$ and $L$ respectively, then show that $KC=LC$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Isn't it visible.. I don't know how to post. If not visible then please tell, I will repost. And if it is visible then we have to prove using the given conditions.

Comment: _We_ can only help you if _we_ know what part you are stuck at. I would suggest you edit the question and add what you have done so far.

Comment: Okay. I was not able to proceed in the very beginning only. How to proceed or what tools we need or what to show first... Or something like a hint may help

Comment: The usual, accepted way to ask a question is by given a problem, (fixing the definitions and relevant framework,) and showing the own work, a starting point, the problem point, providing context, etc. In this case a picture is a minimal effort, that user are expecting, since this is the way the site works. (Showing as much as possible from the own thoughts tends to let potential answers point exact the critical bridge to go further, this spares time and make a fair share of the efforts.) So what have you tried? (No further information results in many downvotes and a close of the thread.)

Comment: The best way to get an answer to problems in geometry is to add a diagram to your post depicting what you have described in words.

Answer (score 1):

**You have asked for a hint. The following method does work so you can, if you wish, try it and ask if you get stuck.**

Take $C$ as the origin and let $x$ and $y$ be unit vectors in the directions $CA$ and $CB$. For convenience assume the triangle is scaled so the vectors $EA=x$ and $DB=y$. Let $CE=\lambda x$ and $CD=\mu y$.

Let the position vector of the centre of the circumcircle of $ADC$ be $r$ then $$|r|^2=|r-\mu y|^2=|r-(\lambda+1)x|^2$$
From this equation you can obtain $r.y$ and $r.x$. Do the same for the circumcentre, with position vector $s$, of the other circle.

Then find $(r-s).(x+y)$. You will obtain zero.